# Like and Dislike button functionality

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement the logic of the Like and Dislike button.
I have a property named **like** with the type of Integer from the server. The **like** value could be either 1, 0 or -1.

1 = like

0 = nothing

-1 = dislike

The default value is 0, so when you click Like button once, the **like** value = 1, you click it the second time, the **like** value = 0.

It is similar to dislike, when Dislike button is clicked, the **like** value = -1, you click it the second time, the **like** value = 0.

Currently, I have this function for updating the value

The Boolean like and dislike properties are for The thumbs icon (they can't be true at the same time), the talkLikeValue is the value I want to send back to the server.

```
var talkLikeValue: Int? = 0
var like: Bool = false
var dislike: Bool = false

func updateLikeAndDislike() {
    if like == true {
        talkLikeValue = 1
        dislike = false
    } else if dislike == true {
        talkLikeValue = -1
        like = false
    }
}
```

and my button.

```
//// Dislike button
Button {
        Task {
            updateLikeAndDislike()
            dislike.toggle()
            await homeVM.likeTalks(like: homeVM.talkLikeValue)
         }
       } label: {
          SystemImageView(
            name: talk.like == -1 ? "hand.thumbsdown.fill" : "hand.thumbsdown",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            color: .blue)
       }
//// like button
Button {
        Task {
            updateLikeAndDislike()
            like.toggle()
            await homeVM.likeTalks(like: homeVM.talkLikeValue)
         }
       } label: {
          SystemImageView(
            name: talk.like == 1 ? "hand.thumbsup.fill" : "hand.thumbsup",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            color: .blue)
       }
```

My code is not working, it sends the correct value to the server 70% of the time and the animation is completely not working. Any thought?

Comment: Consider that `Task{}` means "don't start this code until some time in the unknown future when you feel like it."

Comment: Thank you @matt, I tried to put all of the action into the Task{} but it is not going to do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems kind of overly complicated for what should be a simple toggle function. Maybe try something like this:

```swift
var talkLikeValue = 0

func toggleLikeValue(tappedValue: Int) {
  // Check if value already has the value for the tapped button
  if talkLikeValue == tappedValue {
    // If it is already tapped, then the button is already tapped
    talkLikeValue = 0
  } else {
    // Else just set the value to the tappedValue
    talkLikeValue = tappedValue
  }
}
```

And update your button

```
Button {
        Task {
            toggleLikeValue(-1)
            await homeVM.likeTalks(like: homeVM.talkLikeValue)
         }
       } label: {
          SystemImageView(
            name: talk.talkLikeValue == -1 ? "hand.thumbsdown.fill" : "hand.thumbsdown",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            color: .blue)
       }
//// like button
Button {
        Task {
            toggleLikeValue(1)
            await homeVM.likeTalks(like: homeVM.talkLikeValue)
         }
       } label: {
          SystemImageView(
            name: talk.talkLikeValue == 1 ? "hand.thumbsup.fill" : "hand.thumbsup",
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            color: .blue)
       }
```